# Relative cross section rates using isospin

Tags: homework-and-exercises, scattering-cross-section, isospin-symmetry

There is a step in a solved problem I am not able to make sense of. Such problem finds the relative cross-section rates for the two following reactions using isospin formalism:

\begin{equation*}
 R=  \frac{\sigma (\pi^- + p \rightarrow K^0 + \Sigma^0)}{\sigma (\pi^+ + p \rightarrow K^+ + \Sigma^+)}
\end{equation*}

Jumping to the problematic moment, using Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, ratio turns out to be:
\begin{equation*}
  R = \frac{ \lvert \sqrt{2/9} M_{3/2} - \sqrt{2/9} M_{1/2}  \rvert^2    }{  \lvert   M_{3/2}  \rvert^2    }
\end{equation*}

Where M are the matrix elements of different isospin values.
After this, teacher proceeds to eliminate the $M(1/2)$ element, with a final result of 2/9.

What's the reasoning behind this? Is it because second reaction has no choice of a final $I(1/2)$ state? Or is it that $I(3/2)$ is way more likely to happen?

Comment: Hasn't your teacher explained the reaction goes mostly through the Δ ?

Comment: I'm not even sure what delta means in this context. Could you please clarify?

Comment: It's for your teacher to do. The Δ(1236) is a baryon resonance with spin and isospin 3/2, dominating π-p scattering. It should feature prominently  in your HEP text, if it's any good.

Comment: Hello Cosmas. I'm not sure why you bother answering questions if you predominant answer is "it's for your teacher to do". I appreciate your answer nevertheless. I don't think my teacher expects us to know by heart what baryon resonances dominate every specific scattering, so I guess I'll research why is the 3/2 channel more likely.  Because what I get from your answer is that "it is more likely because it is more likely". I can't use tautologies in the exam! :D

Comment: Your teacher is remiss in not telling you about this: it is *not* an incidental technicality, by far. This site does not address homework or exam questions, with salutary   prejudice! I answer interesting questions, not "things you should have learned in school" and are available to a well-meaning student in every text.  Asking why resonance channels make a reaction more likely is a very different question and should be articulated as such.

Comment: Why resonance channels make a reaction more likely?

Comment: It's part of the analytic structure of the amplitude: the pole of the propagator of the resonance enhances the amplitude.